# c# Regex return all matches (letters range)

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to return all matches from the string and pattern below.
My desired result would be 7 groups: e,f,e,g,e,e
However, the console prints: e, e.

I can understand this method return only first match, so I get only e. But why is it printed twice? The letter e is repeated 4 times in a string.

```
string text = "hello from the regex project";
string pattern = "([e-g])";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match m = r.Match(text);


foreach (var item in m.Groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You have two groups, 0th and 1st. Do you just need to return all occurrences? Then use `Regex.Matches` and just grab `match.Value`s. `Regex.Matches(text, @"(?i)[e-g]").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)`

Comment: @Wiktor thank you and sorry for duplication

Answer (score 0):

You're only taking the first match, you need to work with all the matches
something like:

```
    MatchCollection m = r.Matches(text);

    foreach (var item in m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```